# How to handle int and int64 when parsing json

Tags: c#, json, int64, int32, overflowexception

I have a program that loops through json and grabs the values. This works find until it gets to an integer that is above what int32 handles.

```
2021-09-10 08:00:02.7576|ERROR|System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
```

Is it possible to handle both int32 and int64 in the below? I've tried to use the following but it didn't seem to work

```
int amount = (int)resource.First.ToObject<long>();
```

```
foreach (JToken resource in resources["responseData"]["resources"].ToList())
                  {
                     string propName = resource.ToObject<JProperty>().Name;
                            //int amount = (int)resource.First.ToObject<long>();
                            int amount = resource.First.ToObject<int>();
                            if (resDef["id"]?.ToString() == propName)
                     {
```

Comment: Just use `long` if values can exceed `int.MaxValue` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way around using 'long'. In the commented out code the overflow exception happens after the JToken was cast and returned, when you take your long value and try to stuff it into the int with the static cast.
Try this:

`long amount = resource.First.ToObject<long>();`